# icon as pseudo element rendering issue

Tags: fonts, icons, rendering, render, element

once every 100 reloads or so I've got a problem with pseudo elements. Instead of displaying icons from the icon font, they glitch and render strange symbols. 
And it looks like this:

[image: weird pseudo element content]

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Usually linking to an external CDN for icon fonts is reliable. Where are your icon fonts referenced from?

Try a local reference to the icon fonts e.g. /assets/fonts/icon-font and check if that performs better.

Comment: yup, it's stored locally:)